# Parent element is adding unnecessary whitespace

Tags: html, css

I am making an image slider and for some reason the parent element is adding whitespace at the bottom of parent div for no reason that I can tell. If there is a better way to set up the css then I would really appreciate a pointer. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="imgslider">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li>
            <img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/DevelopImages_PureTisanes_LowRes-11.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/DevelopImages_PureTisanes_LowRes-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>
    </ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#imgslider {
    display: block;
    height: inherit;
}
.bxslider {
    position: relative;
}
.bxslider img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 750px;
    position: absolute;
}
.bxslider img:first-child {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you are getting extra padding from the `ul`?

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/i14gY3O.png) it should show that there is space below the image, thanks!

Comment: In the html you posted you are missing a closing </div>

Comment: As far I remember (I used to use bxslider quite long time ago) it might be extra margin at the bottom for dots to change slides. It's quite common that sliders are doing it, slick slider the same). Check in dev tool, you should find the answer there (or just give us a link ;))

Comment: Doesn't seem to be added by bxslider and no link as it's a localhost. I did however forget to mention that the #imageslider class also has the element of height: inherit;

Comment: check this https://www.wpbeaverbuilder.com/support/q/content-slider-dot-padding/

hope this will give an idea how to fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a not closed div at the end :-)
Maybe this is what causing the issue:

```
    <div id="imgslider">
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <li>
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/DevelopImages_PureTisanes_LowRes-11.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/DevelopImages_PureTisanes_LowRes-1.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: not sure the close div will be there, i think it after the clear div but that IMO =))

Comment: Sorry I missed out the closing div after the clear, really sorry! So it isn't that :/

Comment: Do you still have this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will help but i have read somewhere "**clear:both**" cause adding some space at bottom so you may want to add "**overflow:hidden**" to the parent div (i think it is the div with id "**imgslider**")

```
#imgslider {
    display: block;
    height: inherit;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```